# ¿Cómo se rellena una matriz con números pares aleatorios sin que se repitan?

Tags: c

Tengo que generar números aleatorios y sacar los repetidos. No sé realmente la razón por la cual el código no funciona.

La función es la siguiente:

```
void cargarMatrizAleatoriaParesSinRepetir(int matriz[PAISES][BIMESTRE]) {
    int i;    //Paises
    int k;    //Bimestre

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
            matriz[i][k] = rand() % 11000;
            if (matriz[i][k] % 2 != 0) {
                matriz[i][k] = rand() % 11000;
            }
        printf("%i - ", matriz[i][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Agradezco su ayuda. Tengo bien puesta la biblioteca y he incluido la llamada `srand(time(NULL));`.

Comment: ¿Qué problema tiene exactamente? Estás generando los números correctamente, pero imagino que no sabes cómo hacer que no se repitan, ¿no?. ¿De qué número a qué número deben ser esos números generados? ¿Para qué haces la comprobación `if(matriz[i][k]%2!=0){`?

Answer (score 3):

Veo dos problemas en tu código.

1. Como ya te han mencionado, si quieres solo números pares, al tener un impar, otra llamada a `rand()` no te garantiza que te va a devolver un número par. Un buen truco es sumar o restar uno a cualquier número impar que te devuelva, pero si no te parece aceptable, haz un ciclo que salga hasta que el número devuelto sea par.

   Tomando esta segunda postura, podrías hacer algo como:

   ```
    int num;
    do {
        num = rand() % 11000;
    } while (num %2 != 0);
   ```
2. Para llevar un control de los duplicados, y tomando en cuenta que solamente quieres utilizar 11000 números, no es una loca idea tener un arreglo de 11000 booleanos en memoria (que solo ocupa 11K y podría optimizarse aún más si tomamos solo un bit por número para hacer un *bitmap*), lo que permitiría ver muy rápido si un número ya ha sido asignado o no.

   Tomando una idea similar a la anterior, y suponiendo que ya tenemos un arreglo de X número de booleanos, podríamos hacer un ciclo `do/while` que salga hasta que tenemos un número que no ha sido asignado antes, algo como:

   ```
    int num;
    do {
        do {
            num = rand() % MAXNUMERO;
        } while (num %2 != 0);
    } while (asignado[num]);
    asignado[num] = true;
   ```

   He dejado los dos ciclos anidados para que el código sea fácil de entender, pero podría fácilmente reducirse a un solo ciclo que valide ambas condiciones de salida a la vez.

   Otra posible optimización es tomar en cuenta que solo utilizas números pares, con lo que puedes reducir a la mitad el tamaño del arreglo de control en memoria. Ambas optimizaciones quedan fuera del alcance de esta respuesta.

Poniendo todo junto, usando y declarando constantes, tu función podría quedar así:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

const int PAISES = 6;
const int BIMESTRE = 6;
const int MAXNUMERO = 11000;

void cargarMatrizAleatoriaParesSinRepetir(int matriz[PAISES][BIMESTRE]) {
    int i;    //Paises
    int k;    //Bimestre
    
    bool asignado[MAXNUMERO];
    //inicializamos de manera rápida todas las posiciones del arreglo a false
    memset(asignado, false, MAXNUMERO * sizeof(bool));

    for (i = 0; i < PAISES; i++) {
        for (k = 0; k < BIMESTRE; k++) {
            int num;
            do {
                do {
                    num = rand() % MAXNUMERO;
                } while (num %2 != 0);
            } while (asignado[num]);
            asignado[num] = true;
            matriz[i][k] = num;
            printf("%i - ", matriz[i][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Dado esto, puedes reducir el valor de `MAXNUMERO` a, digamos, 80, y verificar que la función realmente no devuelve números repetidos.

Answer (score 2):

El principal problema es que te puede dar dos veces un impar cuando intentas corregirlo llamando de nuevo al rand().

Yo lo que haría es que si detecto que el número que me dio es impar, le sumo uno y ya tienes un par.

Así:

```
void cargarMatrizAleatoriaParesSinRepetir(int matriz[PAISES][BIMESTRE]) {
int i;    //Paises
int k;    //Bimestre

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for (k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
        matriz[i][k] = rand() % 11000;
        if (matriz[i][k] % 2 != 0) {
            matriz[i][k] +=1;
        }
    printf("%i - ", matriz[i][k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

El otro problema que tienes es evitar los repetidos, digamos que esta parcialmente "resuelto" con el %11000, la probabilidad que te aparezca un repetido para 36 posibilidades es bajo, pero si quieres ser exhaustivo, tendrás que revisar si ese numero ya ha salido antes. Yo recomiendo buscar algún tipo de estructura de datos en la que puedas buscar eficientemente y la rellenes con los números que te van saliendo.

Answer (score 2):

Sí lo que deseas es rellenar una matriz con números pares de forma aleatoria sin que se repitan, simplemente usa el siguiente algoritmo:

**1.-** Generar un número aleatorio con la función `rand()` y guardamos el resultado en una variable `num`.

**2.-** Verificamos si el valor de la variable `num` es impar, si lo es, le sumamos más uno para tener un número par.

**3.-** Rellenamos la matriz en dos en dos pero lo hacemos a partir del número que tenga guardado la variable `num`.

**4.-** Invocamos una función en la cual se encargue de barajar (*desordenar*) los elementos del *array* (cada fila de la matriz en realidad es un *array* unidimensional). En este paso se usa el [algoritmo de Fisher-Yates](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Fisher-Yates).

En código quedaría así:

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> 
#define N   6
#define M   6

void barajar(int[]);
void randomArray2D(int[][M]);

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int matriz[N][M];
    randomArray2D(matriz);
    //Mostramos los elementos de la matriz.
    for(int i = 0; i != N; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j != M; ++j)
            printf("%d\t", matriz[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void randomArray2D(int matriz[][M]) 
{
    int num;  
    //Generamos un número aleatorio.
    num = rand();
    //Verificamos si el número es impar.
    num = (num % 2 == 1) ? (num + 1) : (num);
    //Rellenamos la matriz con números pares sin repetición.
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < M; k++) 
        {
            matriz[i][k] = num;
            num += 2;
        }
    }
    //Barajamos los elementos de cada fila de la matriz.
    for(int i = 0; i != N; ++i)
        barajar(matriz[i]);
}

//Esta función usa el algoritmo de Fisher-Yates para barajar los elementos de cada fila de la matriz.
void barajar(int array[])
{
    int index, aux;
    for(int i = N - 1; i != 0; --i)
    {
        index = rand() % (i+1);
        aux = array[index];
        array[index] = array[i];
        array[i] = aux;
    }
}
```